# create a new object

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsobject

I want to create a new object so as to instantiate and use it several times;

For example, if I want to create an object that has a label and a button inside, how do I? I created a new NSObject but inside it has nothing, then how do I make everything from scratch since there was a viewDidLoad for example (obviously, since it has a view)?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions lead me to think that you're really just starting out. There's nothing wrong with that, but rather than trying to summarize several megabytes of documentation in a few paragraphs, I'm just going to point you to the [iOS Starting Point](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneGeneral/_index.html). I *think* that you're just trying to create a container that can hold other UI components? If so, use a UIView for that. However, don't jump in and try to get something specific done without first reading through some of the Getting Started documents -- you'll just end up back here, and we'll just point you back to the docs. You might like the [Your First iOS Application](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514) guide, as that lets you get your feet wet but explains things along the way.